# List last few dates that are in the past

Tags: php, data-structures

I have this data structure which has names and their birthdays, some of them finished their birthday some of the have it in the future what I want to do is I want to get the last 3 birthdays (so yeah it means for the ones that already had a birthday), I don't really have an idea how to compare them since there are also birthdays that are in the future.

The format of the date I am using is `month/day/year`.

I know you would like to see for my effort but as I said the future date/s are confusing me so I really don't know how it will work.

```
$birthdays = [
    'person1' => ['name' => 'aa','date' => '10/08/2021'],
    'person2' => ['name' => 'bb','date' => '09/25/2021'],
    'person3' => ['name' => 'cc','date' => '04/04/2022'],
    'person4' => ['name' => 'dd','date' => '12/12/2021'],
    'person5' => ['name' => 'gg','date' => '05/29/2021'],
    'person6' => ['name' => 'h','date' => '08/12/2021'],
];
```

The result in the end should be the names (dd, aa, bb).

Comment: DO you get this data from a database?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no actually it's just static one, which I modify it however I want to.

Comment: I would start by sorting the array on date, although to do that you will have to amend the array to use a sensible sortable date format first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$birthdays = [
    'person1' => ['name' => 'aa','date' => '10/08/2021'],
    'person2' => ['name' => 'bb','date' => '09/25/2021'],
    'person3' => ['name' => 'cc','date' => '04/04/2022'],
    'person4' => ['name' => 'dd','date' => '12/12/2021'],
    'person5' => ['name' => 'gg','date' => '05/29/2021'],
    'person6' => ['name' => 'h','date' => '08/12/2021'],
];
$s = [];
foreach($birthdays as $k=>$v)
{
  $s[] = time()-strtotime($v['date']);
}
sort($s);
print_r($s);
```